# Not work "Migrate" and mysql in laravel project

Tags: laravel, migrate

I install laravel and create project.
I Configed configuration file database and create database in mysql(mysql runnig in wamp server).
I want use migrate for create table in mysql,but i should wait a lot of time and see error.
What shoud i do?

Comment: what error, please attach

Comment: I shoud wait a lot of time to see this error:PDOException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: attach the create table class, there must be something horribly wrong to get time out on create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you run these command in terminal:

```
    php artisan migrate --force
```

The migrate:refresh will roll back all of your migrations then execute the migrate command.this will re-creates your entire database.

```
       php artisan migrate:refresh
```

This will absolutely help you,run this command:

```
 php artisan migrate:fresh
```

if it did't help please chick out this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Comment: first look you database login info in the .env file is that correct then run these command.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you entered your mysql Server credentials in the database config, but you have to edit the .env file. Values in there overwrite config settings.